# manipulating data values from csv file while using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

I need to generate a plot using data from a csv file. I am using matplotlib.
However, in my plot I want to take inverse of the value given in csv file. Can I do this easily without having to manipulate the csv file itself. Basically, is there a way in matplotlib that when I specify the column to be used, I may specify to take reciprical values? e.g. if value is 10 then during plotting the value should be 1/10=0.1

I have referred to this link https://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-gapminder/09-plotting/ to get an understanding of possible options in matplotlib. I also checked forums for any similar question. I am new to python and matplotlib so please excuse me if this seems too trivial.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("test_plot_data.csv")
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='height',y='weight')
plt.savefig('my_figure.png')
plt.close()


The input test file:
number1,number2,product,height,weight
2,5,10,5,100
6,7,42,10,110
7,8,56,15,120
8,9,72,20,200
```

The current code just generates a plot using the values in csv file. I would like to know if there is any available way in matplotlib to manipulate the data it is picking from csv file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems rather unrelated to matplotlib. `df["invweight"] = 1.0 / df["weight"]` would create a new column in the dataframe which you can use for plotting.

Comment: Thanks so much. It does the trick for now :)